# How to add a new column to a dataframe based on calculation of other

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with has columns `[value, min, max, count]`. I'm trying to add a new column to my dataframe based on a calculation of the existing columns

```
df[new_col] = (df['value'] - df['min'])/df['max']
```

but apparently it doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: Apparently? Why not?

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the DataFrame - [mcve]

Comment: How it doesn't work? Do you get errors or it returns values that are not expected?

Answer (score -1):

if `new_col` is a string, for example `new_col = 'result'` then it should work:

```
df[new_col] = (df['value'] - df['min'])/df['max']
```